# Problemas con npm run dev, Laravel+vue no guarda los component que creo

Tags: vue.js, npm, laravel-8

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en laravel con vue, ejecute `npm run dev` para que compilara los archivos js, si compilaba todo, pero hubo un punto donde dejo de compilar todos los components y solo compila el principal, no sale ningun error, simplemente no compila los demas.
**`vite.config.js`**:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

**package.json:**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.5",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.37"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue-router": "^4.2.3",
        "vuex": "^4.1.0"
    }
}
```

Al principio si compilaba todo pero cuando cree un `ArticulosComponent.vue` y lo estaba agregando escribi algo mal y salio un error al compilar, pero despues de corregirlo dejo de compilar los demas archivos `.vue`. Realmente recien inicio en esto asi que no entiendo que es lo que pasa, puesto que le pase el proyecto a un amigo y a el si se le compila todos los archivos `.vue`

Comment: Debes tener algun error en algun lado, y tiene que estar saliendo, o al compilar, o al ejecutar. pero sin eso dificil ayudarte

Comment: es que lo raro es que el proyecto se lo paso a un amigo mio y si funciona correctamente el npm run dev, o sea cuando se hace un cambio en un archivo sale el vite hmr update '....AppComponent', pero en mi laptop solo se guarda los js y uno de .vue